# How would I construct a php JSON POST request based on the Curl example?

Tags: php, json, post

I have an API endpoint I'm trying to post to. The only example they have is a curl request. I'm having a hard time properly constructing the php json post.

Here is the curl request:

```
$ curl -XPOST https://myzbiz.pike13.com/api/v2/desk/people \
    -H "Authorization: Bearer XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX" \
    -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
    -d '{
        "person": {
            "first_name": "Jane",
            "last_name": "Client",
            "email": "janeclient@example.com"
        }
    }'
```

And here is my PHP request that I constructed:

```
$url2 = 'https://example.com/api';
$data2 = array('access_token'=>$jsonData->access_token, 'first_name'=>$userData[person][first_name], 'last_name'=>$userData[person][last_name], 'email'=>$userData[person][email]);
$options2 = array(
        'http' => array(
        'header'  => "Authorization: Bearer tokenstringgoeshere\r\n" . "Content-Type: application/json\r\n",
        'method'  => 'POST',
        'content' => json_encode($data2, JSON_FORCE_OBJECT),
    )
);
$context2  = stream_context_create($options2);
$result2 = file_get_contents($url2, false, $context2);
$string2 = $result2;
$jsonData2 = json_decode($string2);

header('Content-Type: application/json');
echo json_encode($jsonData2);
```

It keeps throwing an error on the `file_get_contents()` line like so:

```
PROCESS RESPONSE 
Warning: file_get_contents(apiUrlHere): failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
 in /home/ubuntu/workspace/process.php on line 63

Call Stack:
    0.0009     242968   1. {main}() /home/ubuntu/workspace/process.php:0
    0.3491     256144   2. file_get_contents() /home/ubuntu/workspace/process.php:63
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `PHP Curl` to make POST request.

```
$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://myzbiz.pike13.com/api/v2/desk/people");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "{\n        \"person\": {\n            \"first_name\": \"Jane\",\n            \"last_name\": \"Client\",\n            \"email\": \"janeclient@example.com\"\n        }\n    }");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);

$headers = array();
$headers[] = "Authorization: Bearer XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX";
$headers[] = "Content-Type: application/json";
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);

$result = curl_exec($ch);
if (curl_errno($ch)) {
    echo 'Error:' . curl_error($ch);
}
curl_close ($ch);
```

`$result` will contain the response data.